# Beginner: need to import Beautiful Soup 4 into Python

Tags: python, import, beautifulsoup

I learned Python from codecademy and now I'm trying to learn to use it to mine data from a website. I don't have my own Python system set up (only ever used the Codecademy one) and so I need advice on what to download to run my code and how I can import the Beautiful Soup package into it so I can use BS4. I am on a Mac, running OSX 10.9.4.
Thanks!

Comment: What is your OS? Have you look at the downloads page of the Python website? If not, you should, and then try to install BeautifulSoup, and come up with your actual problem, if any

Comment: I downloaded python 3.4.1 from python.org but it was not a very user friendly interface and I couldn't get it to import beautifulsoup. NOt really sure how I do that anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Python 3.4, you should have either `pip` or the `pip` auto-bootstrap already installed, under the name `pip3`.* So all you need to do is this:

```
$ pip3 install beautifulsoup4
```

Adding `sudo` as appropriate, of course.

If you somehow don't have `pip`, you should get it. [Tool Recommendations](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/current.html) in the Packaging User Guide is the first place you should look for up-to-date instructions, but it will just link you to the [`pip`](https://pip.pypa.io/) docs, which will tell you to do the following:

- Download [`get-pip.py`](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)
- Install it with `python3 get-pip.py` (again with `sudo` if necessary)

---

`pip` is a Unix command-line program, not a Python command. So, if you know nothing about Unix systems like Mac OS X, here's what you do:

First, launch Terminal.app, either via Spotlight (hit Cmd+Space and start typing Terminal.app, and when the full name shows up, hit Return) or through Finder (open Applications from the sidebar, then open Utilities, then you'll find Terminal.app).

Now you'll get a text window running the bash shell. Just like Python prompts you for the next command with `>>>`, bash prompts you for the next command with `$`, or maybe something like `My Computer:/Users/me$`. So, after that prompt, you type `pip3 install beautifulsoup4`. If it works, you're done, you now have bs4 installed, so next time you run Python 3.4 (whether via IDLE, or on the command line with `python3`, or anywhere else), you'll be able to import it.

If you get an error saying something about `Permission denied`, you need to use `sudo` to manage your Python. You know how GUI programs like System Preferences sometimes pop up a dialog asking for you to type your username and password to give them administrator permissions? `sudo` is the way you do that from the command line. You type `sudo pip3 install beautifulsoup4`, and it will ask for your password. After you type it in, everything should work.

If this all sounds like way too much, you may want to consider getting a more powerful Python IDE (Integrated Development Environment) than IDLE. I haven't tried them all (and Stack Overflow isn't a good place to look for recommendations, but you can google for them), but I know at least some of them have a nice graphical way to manage your installed packages so you don't have to use the command line and `pip`. PyCharm and PyDev (part of Eclipse) seem to be popular. However, you really should consider going through a basic tutorial on using the Mac as a Unix system at some point; there are so many concepts you'll need to write even simple Python scripts.

---

<sub>* Slightly oversimplifying [PEP 394](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/), when you have both 2.x and 3.x on the same system (which you do—Apple preinstalled 2.7 for you, and you installed 3.4), you use `python3`, `pip3`, etc. to run the 3.x version.</sub>

<sub>** How do you know if `sudo` is necessary if you don't understand basic Unix administration? If you've installed Python 3.x via Homebrew, it's not. Via MacPorts or Fink, it is. Via the Python.org binary installer, or a third-party binary installer, it depends on the settings you chose at install time, which you will not remember… so just try without `sudo`; if it works, you don't need `sudo` for `pip`, but if you get a permissions error, try again with `sudo`, and if that works, then you need `sudo` for `pip`.</sub>

Comment: I think I'm more confused than ever! I downloaded Python 3.4.1 from python.org for Mac OSX 10.6 or higher. I open the editor. It says python 3.4.1 shell. When I type in $ pip3 install bs4 I get the error "invalid syntax" for the $ sign. I don't know what sudo is. Someone talk to me like I'm a five year old trying to do this, I'm so confused!

Comment: @DazedandConfused: OK, let me edit the question a bit, and try to explain it to a 5-year-old (or an expert classic Mac user who fell through a wormhole from 1988, who'd have the same problem on a modern Mac system… this isn't you being stupid or anything, it's just you not having Unix experience, which is reasonable).

Comment: thank you it ran a program or whatever and it gave me the message Successfully installed bs4. This makes so much more sense. Thank you very much for taking the time to write it all out, I very much appreciate it! You're awesome.

Comment: @DazedandConfused: just start python and use an `import` statement, or do the same at the top of your program. I can't remember if it's `import bs4` or `import beautifulsoup`, or `import beautifulsoup4` and I'm not at a computer, but it's one of those three.

Answer (score 2):

To install python easy_install on OSX:

```
curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py

sudo python distribute_setup.py

sudo rm distribute_setup.py

sudo easy_install pip
```

After installing the python easy_install package.  you can then run:

```
    easy_install beautifulsoup4
```

This will allow you to actually include beautifulsoup4 in your python script:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

From there, you will have access to the method BeautifulSoup and I'm assuming you can take it From there.  Example:

```
    soup=BeautifulSoup(urlContent)
```

Comment: This is very out-of-date information. Don't tell people to install `distribute` instead of `setuptools`. And don't tell them to use `easy_install` instead of `pip`, either.

Comment: I also just realized that you're telling him to install this into his system Python 2.7, which (a) already _has_ `easy_install`, and (b) isn't going to help him use bs4 in Python 3.4.